# Acesso ao MySql

Tags: php

Antes de migrar para o dominio ".xyz" na Hostinger, o script a seguir funcionava normalmente. Agora, não acessa os dados.

Por que não apresenta o numero total de registros? - Linha 32
Por que o laço While não funciona? - Linha 38

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    <!   teste_conexao.php  ><html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');

$host = "mysql.hostinger.com.br";
$usuario = "u340822322_rfmc";
$senha_conect = "n6XrRbxHFQ1T";
$bd = "u340822322_pcl1";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha_conect, $bd);



if($conn){
    echo "conectado"."<br>";
}else{
    echo "nao conectado"."<br>";
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$data = date('d/m/y - H:i:s'); 
echo "<br>" . $data . "<br><br>"; 

echo "<br>passou aqui - 01";

$selecao = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM tabela_precos');

$total = mysqli_num_rows($selecao); // numero de registros do arquivo
echo "<br>===<br> Nº de registros = " . $total . "<br>===<br>";

$linha=array();
$n=0;
echo "<br>passou aqui - 02";

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($selecao)) {
    echo "<br>passou aqui - 03";
    $linha[]=$dados;

    $linha1=$linha[$n]['nome_picole'];

    echo $linha1 . "<br>";
    $n++;
}

echo "<br>passou aqui - 04";

?>
<br>
finalizou aqui.
</html>
```

---

O resultado é:

```
conectado

16/10/18 - 08:09:03


passou aqui - 01
===
Nº de registros = 
===

passou aqui - 02
passou aqui - 04
finalizou aqui.
```

---

1) Por que não apresenta o numero total de registros? - Linha 32 - A tabela tem 17 registros
2) Por que o laço While não funciona? - Linha 38

Comment: Tenta editar a tua pergunta está uma confusão. Não sabemos as linhas do código que estás a falar, mete um cometário a dizer "problema 1)" ou algo desse género. E explica melhor qual é o problema.

Comment: Entretanto se estás a tentar mudar de domínio também tiveste de mudar a base de dados? Logo tens que dar importo das tabelas da base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Caro,

O nome do database dentro do servidor não mudou? Parece que você está conectando corretamente no banco, mas não está acessando o database.

Verifique o nome do database no banco de dados, e tente acessá-lo com o comando **mysql_select_db** após a conexão.

Seria algo como

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha_conect, $bd);

if($conn){
    echo "conectado"."<br>";
}else{
    echo "nao conectado"."<br>";
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname', $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Não foi possível acessar o database dbname' . mysql_error());
}
```

Documentação do comando: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: Eu criei um novo database, no novo domínio. E o que está acontecendo é isto mesmo: conecta corretamente, mas não acessa os dados.

Comment: E você experimentou o comendo para seleção do database? funcionou?

Comment: Experimentei sim. Continua do mesmo jeito.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar:

```
$selecao = mysqli_query('SELECT count(*) FROM tabela_precos');
```

da o fetch e ele vai retornar o numero de registros

Comment: Não funcionou, amigo. Informa que está conectado, mas não dá acesso à tabela.

Answer (score 0):

A query está falhando porque você não passou a conexão. Conforme indicado no [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), ficaria assim:

```
$selecao = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM tabela_precos');
```

Comment: Assim funcionou. Muito obrigado. Desculpe a demora em responder, mas fiquei sem internet por muitos dias. Muito obrigado.